# Why am I getting more groups than what I see via User interface in SharePoint?

Tags: permissions, groups

I am trying to get the sharepoint groups for a particular **subsite**, but I am getting more groups then what I see via UI. I created a test subsite and I still see more groups. For example: Via UI I see these groups "Test Owners", "Test Visitors", "Test Members", but using powershell I see these extra groups: "Finance Owners", Designers, Act Content Admins, General Workspace Owners, etc.

This is the powershell script I am using. It is really simple.

```
function GetWebGroups($web){

    if($web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True)
    {
        # I have tried using SPGroup
        $groups = $web.Groups
        foreach($group in $groups)
        {
            Write-Host $group.Name -f Yellow
        }

        # And I have tried using Roleassignments
        foreach($webRoleAssignment in $web.RoleAssignments) 
        {
                Write-Host $webRoleAssignment.Member.Name
        }   
    }

}
```

I have broken the inheritance, but I still get extra groups which I don't see them via user interface.

What could be the reason?

Comment: By the group names you mentioned in your question, I think that you are trying to get users of your subsite. Please tell me if i am worng.

Comment: Please check if it works for you..https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2557cda9-9d31-4774-af0b-d44f7d6afb8c/how-to-get-all-users-are-groups-under-sharepoint-subsite-using-powershell-?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: @Hardik, no I am referring to groups themselves and not users.

Comment: Site Collection Groups or only subsite groups?

Comment: It is mentioned in my post above. I set it to bold. It is subsite.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you are passing in `$web`. But If you groups from specific subsite than you need to give specific subsite URL in your `$web` to get all groups for given subsite URL.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
    //Pass Subsite URL to get only subsite groups    
    $web = Get-SPWeb http://server/sites/yourSubSite

    function GetWebGroups($web){

        if($web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True)
        {
            # I have tried using SPGroup
            $groups = $web.SiteGroups
            foreach($group in $groups)
            {
                Write-Host $group.Name -f Yellow
            }

            # And I have tried using Roleassignments
            foreach($webRoleAssignment in $web.RoleAssignments) 
            {
                    Write-Host $webRoleAssignment.Member.Name
            }   
        }

    }
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: sorry, but it is not helpful.

Comment: Can you prove the code for what you are passing in **$web**?

Comment: It is exactly what you added:  `$web = Get-SPWeb http://intfin/sites/regions/mytest`

Comment: Have you checked here?...https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2557cda9-9d31-4774-af0b-d44f7d6afb8c/how-to-get-all-users-are-groups-under-sharepoint-subsite-using-powershell-?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: Please check updated answer. It will work for you.

Comment: `SiteGroups` return all the groups in the site collection. I don't want that. I want only the specified groups of that particular subsite.